# CSS class background image horizontal positioning?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to position a facebook/youtube/twitter button on a div that is 318 pixels across (so about 106 pixels per button).

**Expected Ouput**

[image: expected layout]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/dseazq4c.zqc.png))</sub>

I'm using float and display:inline on each button as its being rendered. I've provided my code below.

**CSS CODE**

```
#socialController{
width: 318px;
background-color:#fff;
display: inline;
}
.socialmedia
{
width:106px;
height:20px;
float:left;
vertical-align:middle;
background-position:center center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:#373737;
}
.socialmedia:hover{
background-color:#444
}
#sm_fb{
background-image:url(../img/fb.png)
}
#sm_tw{
background-image:url(../img/tw.png)
}
#sm_yt{
background-image:url(../img/yt.png)
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="socialController">
<a href="#" class="socialmedia" id="sm_fb" title="CSGONZ Facebook"></a>
<a href="#" class="socialmedia" id="sm_yt" title="CSGONZ Youtube"></a>
<a href="#" class="socialmedia" id="sm_tw" title="CSGONZ Twitter"></a>
</div>
```

But the problem is I'm not reaching my expected Horizontal positioning.. but instead I'm getting a vertical positioning of the buttons.

**Actual Output**

[image: actual output]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/2mce1tlk.53i.png))</sub>

What is the problem? and what am I missing? to achieve a horizontal layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
#socialController {
width: 318px;
background-color:#fff;
display: block;
}
```

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/CQTus/

Comment: Hey I've already tried that before I made the post, any other ideas?

Comment: For me, it works this way: http://jsfiddle.net/CQTus/

Comment: I think your links or your container is getting some style from previous declarations and the ones you just copypasted here are overwritten by them. You should check the actual styles the elements got at Firebug or something like that.

Comment: Thanks skywlkr, I figured out it was another section of CSS causing the problem. lol

Comment: @Killrawr hehe, see my answer, I just posted it when you accepted this answer;) So I was too late one second I guess...

Answer (score 1):

display: inline-block; should be applied to socialmedia, not socialController

Comment: I applied the change, but I'm still getting my links displaying vertically and not horizontally :( any other ideas?

Comment: Not really, should be working: http://jsfiddle.net/7tcbT/

Answer (score 1):

I think you must use a list to display your buttons in a horizontal line.

Try [this](http://www.cssmenumaker.com/menu/grey-impression-drop-down-menu-0): it's a tutorial (with source code) for a horizontal menu in CSS.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Any chance you could give me an implementation based off my css? :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/6PaY4/

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Killrawr Check the demo I posted here. It should work for you

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal like this:

See this [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/fjudW/) Example!

[image]

**CSS**

```
#socialController{
  width: 318px;
  background-color:#fff;
  display: block;         /* display the wrapper as a block */
}
.socialmedia {
  width:106px;
  height:20px;
  display:block;          /* display the element as a block */
  float:left;             /* float the elements to place them side by side */
  background-position:center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color:#373737;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly valid as it stands...

See the example i made from [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/hP5ss/)

You must have an error elsewhere. Look for another declaration in your css which overrides the styles you provided. There must be one declaration like this: `a{display:block}` Alter it accordingly.

Comment: +1 for the effort :) thank you!

Comment: @Killrawr Did I make the right guess?

Comment: Yeah you did.. the problem was that somewhere else in my code was conflicting with the positioning.. thus giving me the unexpected result.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it was something else in CSS causing the glitch, thanks everyone for the answers and reassurance :)